# How do I check which app a given view belongs to?

Tags: django

I'm writing a middleware with `process_view` method and I want it to apply only to the views in my app (not `django.contrib.auth` and other imported ones). How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use request url like this

```
def process_request(self, request):
    if request.path.startswith('any_prefix'):
        # do something
    else:
        # do other thing
```

also you can get view function file like this:

```
process_view(request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
    if view_func.__module__ in ['module list']:
        # do something
    else:
        # do other thing
```

in this solution if your view wrapped checking module may not work.